# How to create a button to appear and disappear a patch label in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a beginner question: I would like to create a button to show patch coordinates. This I managed to do. But, I would like to click once to show the patch coordinates and to click the button again to make the patch coordinate disappear. Is it possible? I found using hidden? could work, but hidden? is for turtles and I didn't find this information in the dictionary at least the way I searched.

```
ask patches [
ifelse hidden? = false [ ;; it is not possible
 set plabel  (word "(" pxcor "," pycor ")") ] 
   [  ]
   ]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "hide" the label you can just empty it and reset it, when you want to show it. So when the button was clicked and the plabel is empty, you set it. When the button was clicked and the plabel is not empty, you delete it.

```
to show_hide_labels
  ask patches [
    ifelse plabel = "" 
    [
      set plabel  (word "(" pxcor "," pycor ")") 
    ] 
    [ 
      set plabel ""
    ]
  ]
end
```